# How's analytic continuation done in Mathematica?

Tags: special-functions

I have the following expression:
$$I_1=\frac{\sqrt{a} c^{1-n} \Gamma (n-1) \, _2F_1\left(1,n-1;\frac{1}{2};\frac{b^2}{a c}\right)-\sqrt{\pi } b c^{\frac{1}{2}-n} \Gamma
   \left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right) \left(1-\frac{b^2}{a c}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}-n}}{2 a^{3/2} \Gamma (n)}$$
It is supposed to converge in the domain $|\frac{b^2}{ac}| < 1$, and should be equal to the following expressions, as long as $b^2<ac$:
$$I_2=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x\: d{x}}{(ax^2+2bx+c)^{n}},$$
and,
$$I_3=\frac{(-1)^n}{(n-1){!}{!}}\frac{\partial^{n-2}}{\partial c^{n-2}}\Big(\frac{1}{2(ac-b^2)}-\frac{b}{2(ac-b^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}} cot^{-1}(\frac{b}{\sqrt{ac-b^2}})\Big)\; [b^2<ac]$$

For the same integral in $I_2$, it is also found that for $0<ac<b^2$, there's the following expression:
$$I_4=\frac{(-1)^n}{(n-1){!}{!}}\frac{\partial^{n-2}}{\partial c^{n-2}}\Big(\frac{1}{2(ac-b^2)}+\frac{b}{4(b^2-ac)^{\frac{3}{2}}} \ln\Big(\frac{b+\sqrt{b^2-ac}}{b-\sqrt{b^2-ac}}\Big)\Big)\; [0<ac<b^2]$$
which, for all positive real values of (a,b,c), converges in the region $|\frac{ac}{b^2}|<1$.

However, it is found that numerically, $I_1$ agrees with both $I_3$ (which is expected) and $I_4$ (which is unexpected, owing to the two corresponding to different regions of convergence) to a remarkable degree as it does with $I_2$ (which is expected).

Let me show the table containing the results of this numerical evaluation:
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
\text{(a,b,c)} & \text{n} & \text{$I_2$} & \text{RHS ($I_3$, $I_4$)} & \text{$I_1$} & \text{|$I_2$-RHS|} & \text{|$I_1$-$I_2$|} & \text{|$I_1$-RHS|} \\ \hline
\text{(1,2,1)} & 5 & 0.0045` & 0.0045`,0.0045` & 0.0045` & 0.`,0.` & O(10^{-18}) & O(10^{-18}),O(10^{-18}) \\ \hline
\text{(3,7,5)} & 5 & 2.87*10^{-6} & 2.87*10^{-6},2.87*10^{-6} & 2.87*10^{-6} & O(10^{-22}),O(10^{-21}) & O(10^{-21}) & O(10^{-21}),O(10^{-20}) \\ \hline
\text{(3,1,5)} & 5 & 0.000031` & 0.000031`,0.000031` & 0.000031` & O(10^{-21}),O(10^{-20}) & O(10^{-21}) & O(10^{-20}),O(10^{-20})
\end{array}$$
where, only the real parts of the numerically evaluated results for the corresponding expressions have been taken into consideration (whatever imaginary terms came out during the process turned out to be extremely small to play much of an important role anywhere- you can check this for yourselves).

I suspect that this fine numerical agreement between $I_1$ and $I_4$ and between $I_3$ and $I_4$ is due to analytic continuation which is probably being done by *Mathematica* **automatically**, but so far, I haven't found a solid evidence behind this hypothesis. If *Mathematica* does indeed perform the analytic continuation all by itself, I would also like to know how it does so.

Comment: So the question about Wolfram Mathematica programming is? And you have tried to figure out how? Documentation for `LegendreP` does say *"Type 2 represents an analytic continuation of type 1 outside the unit circle."* BTW, welcome to Mma.SE. Start by taking the [tour] now and learning about [asking](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O) and what's [on-topic](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O). **Brief** context is appreciated, and minimal working example of code in [formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX) most of the time needed. That normally help us to help you.

Comment: Ok I shall edit my question and add the necessary details asap